# Angular one page site dont work properly when enables $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: html, angularjs, symfony, single-page-application

I have an application with the following routes on the server side

- Main path: `/`
- Api path: `/api/*`
- Partials path `/partials/*`

I have a single page application with angular, with the following routes

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {templateUrl: '/partials/home', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/list', {templateUrl: '/partials/list', controller: 'ListCtrl'})
      .when('/details/:id', {templateUrl: '/partials/details', controller: 'DetailsCtrl'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

The app works fine I can navigate between home, go to list and view details. but if i copy the url (or press F5) in any url different from `'/'` example: `http://localhost/details/64c6eb79392e` i get an 404 (Is logical since the server side does not know about that route).

How i can solve this.

I'm using Symfony2 for build my server side application

### Update

this is my `.htaccess` file (I'm using the symfony defaults)

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]    
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>        
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: use `htaccess` to point everything in directory to your app entry point on server

Comment: @charlietfl exist some way to make this without touch a .htaccess file like a pattern in symfony returns the same controller

Comment: i don't know symfony to know how to over ride routing. One thing to consider also though is whether or not you want server side fallback for SEO purposes

Comment: Not interested in SEO, is a private application. It is not to be using '#' on routes

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in symfony, I've done t with other frameworks like codeigniter, put whole symfony in another directory, just have `app.php` point at a single controller in that other directory. Then I think the htaccess you currently  have would work as it is. Otherwise would look how to make all routes point to same controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a controller action in Symfony which generates index template for any given url as the LAST route (so your /api/ and /partials/ would still work), something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{any}", name="any", requirements={"any" = ".*"})
 * @Template("DemoBundle:Index:index.html.twig")
 */
public function anyAction($any)
{
    return array();
}
```

This will generate the index page for any url without issueing 404, and it will be up to AngularJS to route it