# Angularjs template in Symfony 2 project

Tags: php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to use a bootstrap theme angularjs based in a symfony 2 project; i have a bundle with administration gui, so i have following situation:

```
Resources
    |
    |------public
    |         |
    |         |----css
    |         |      | ...
    |         |
    |         |----js
    |              |---- angular.js
    | 
    |------views
```

This theme use two angularjs templates (template1.html, template2.html). 
What is the best way to configure symfony to work with this theme?

Comment: could you clarify on what you want to configure?

Comment: I would like to know where is better put templates in project structure, for example under views. Than i don't know how to configure in the right way the symfony routes to work with angular templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some test, i figure out a solution to my problem. i think that i good solution to use angular.js template inside a symfony bundle is put templates under bundle resources/public path and then control the output name generated from assetic using output parameter. 
For example:

```
Resources
    |
    |----public
    |       |
    |       |-----css
            |
            |-----js
            |
            |-----templates
            |         |
                      |-----dashboard.html
```

and in twig template:

```
{% javascripts '@AdminBundle/Resources/public/templates/dashboard.html' output='admin/templates/dashboard.html'%}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

So lauching assetic with:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

it will generate angularjs template (dashboard.html) under web/templates directory.

In this way angular templates are out of control of twig template engine and this point can be an advantage in some situations. I don't know if this is the best solution to my problem, but for shure it's consistent with angular.js and symfony logic.

Answer (score -1):

Put the Angular template files directly to your web directory, as they dont need to be rendered by twig.

As for the routing, I understand that you want to leave the routing to AngularJS, so just create a symfony controller, which renders the index page for any given url like in this answer: [Angular one page site dont work properly when enables $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708352/angular-one-page-site-dont-work-properly-when-enables-locationprovider-html5mod/27126330#27126330)